# Ruby on Rails reporting tools?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, report

I am looking for a report generation tool in ruby or rails which allows the user to define a template, then fetch data into the created template.

I have been looking through "[The Ruby Box: reporting section.](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/reporting.html)"

There are two reporting tools I have looked at:

1. **[Thin Reports](http://www.thinreports.org/):** It is really good. You can create your own report template with the template editor. Then you can produce PDF reports using [thinreports](http://rubygems.org/gems/thinreports/) gems.
2. **[ODF Report:](https://github.com/sandrods/odf-report)** You can create a template ODF file using Open Office and MS Word, and you can use that template to generate the report.

Both of these solutions lack the ability to draw charts. Does anyone know of similar reporting tools that can draw charts within a given report?

I have tried the [RTF Ruby Library](http://ruby-rtf.rubyforge.org/). It works, but shares the limitation that it cannot draw charts and graphs.

The minimum requirements are:

1. Able to create customizable templates. (e.g. design layout, set font size, color, embed images etc.)
2. Able to draw tables and charts.
3. Template could be in Docx or excel or xml or any other common file format.
4. Report output report must be in Docx or RTF format.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [`axlsx`](https://github.com/randym/axlsx) gem is relatively new but seems like a good library. I haven't seen it used for anything more than simple tables yet, but it supposedly supports a lot of other [Office Open XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) components and features.

From the README:

> With Axlsx you can create excel worksheets with charts, images (with links), automated and fixed column widths, customized styles, functions, tables, conditional formatting, print options, comments, merged cells, auto filters, file and stream serialization as well as full schema validation.

If you are using [ActiveRecord](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html), there is also [`acts_as_axlsx`](https://github.com/randym/acts_as_xlsx) from the same author.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example I found that uses googlecharts api to produce charts for Thinreports:

[Embed Graph using GoogleChartAPI](http://osc.matsukei.net/projects/thinreports/wiki/Example_Embed_graph_using_GoogleChartAPI)

I have not used it though myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Pentaho reporting tool](http://www.sherito.org/p/what-is-pentaho-reporting.html) for your purpose. Pentaho Reporting is a suite of open-source reporting tools which allows you to create relational and analytical reports from a wide range of data-sources. The Pentaho Reporting Engine is able to create PDF, Excel, HTML, Text, Rich-Text-File and XML and CSV outputs of your data.

Comment: But this is Java, and the question was about Ruby on Rails